# How to set font size in Latex table?

Tags: tables, fontsize

I have the following table with column linewidth. I want to set the font size of the table to some specific value. Several suggestions say that a code like `p{0.4in}` will work. I tried `p{0.18\linewidth}{0.4in}` but it is not working. How to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2em} % for the horizontal padding
\caption{A table}
\label{tab:42}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{0.18\linewidth} | p{0.20\linewidth} |}
        %Head row starts************
        \hline
        Column1 & Column2 \\
        \hline
        Data1 & Data2 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question is somewhat contradictory. You mention wanting to change the font size to a specific value, but also mention suggestions such as `p` type columns, which itself do not alter the font size but the available width of a column. What exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: If you want a decent looking table, start by getting rid of the `\resizebox`. Resizing tables will inevitably result in inconsistent fonts sizes and line widths throughout the document.

Comment: @leandriis It is my mistake. I'm new to Latex and so much overwhelmed with numerous codes. How should I proceed if I avoid `\resizebox`?

Comment: How to proceed depends on the expected output. How exactly should your table look like? How wide should your columns be and what kind of contents will they contain (short word, numbers, longer sencences, lists, or something entirely different). Please clarify.

Comment: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` makes it impossible to set any font size, start by removing that, then you can uae any latex size command you want such as \small or \footnotesize if you need the text to be smaller

Comment: perhaps it is what you need, it is hard to tell, but you are setting very narrow columns, `\begin{tabular}{ |p{0.18\linewidth} | p{0.20\linewidth} |}` means your table will be around a third of the width of the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I know. My other tables have 6 to 7 columns. In those cases, whenever I am removing cell padding (for accommodation) using `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2em}`, the font is becoming a little bigger compared to other tables.

Comment: @PSNayak the font size is only changing if you are using `\resizebox` which is why you should almost never apply scaling to tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already pointed out in a comment, nobody should *ever* employ `\resizebox` -- or its close relative, `\scalebox` -- to force the tabular-like material to occupy a given width, say, `\linewidth`.

Instead, use a `tabularx` or a `tabular*` environment to set the overall width to, say, `\linewidth`. That way, you'll avoid getting wildly inconsistent font sizes across tables. Then, as needed and appropriate for your table, consider things like replacing one or more of the current column specs with column types that allow automatic line breaking.

If you must still adjust the font size, you may use one of LaTeX's many font size changing macros. The following screenshot shows the effects of employing `\Large`, `\large`, `\normalsize` (the default), `\small`, `\footnotesize`, and `\scriptsize`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % make the tables look less cramped
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{A full-width \texttt{tabularx} environment at various font sizes\strut} \label{tab:42}

\Large
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | X  |}
        \hline
        Column1 & Column2 \\
        \hline
        Data & \texttt{\textbackslash Large} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\medskip

\large
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | X  |}
        \hline
        Column1 & Column2 \\
        \hline
        Data & \texttt{\textbackslash large} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\medskip

\normalsize % that's the default
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | X  |}
        \hline
        Column1 & Column2 \\
        \hline
        Data & \texttt{\textbackslash normalsize} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\medskip

\small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | X  |}
        \hline
        Column1 & Column2 \\
        \hline
        Data & \texttt{\textbackslash small} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\medskip

\footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | X  |}
        \hline
        Column1 & Column2 \\
        \hline
        Data & \texttt{\textbackslash footnotesize} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\medskip

\scriptsize
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | X  |}
        \hline
        Column1 & Column2 \\
        \hline
        Data & \texttt{\textbackslash scriptsize} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was also answered here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563498/making-latex-tables-smaller).

Personally, I like this method:

```latex
\scalebox{0.7}{
  \begin{tabular}
    ...
  \end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this piece of advice is simply terrible, as it flies in the face of just about every known principle of decent typesetting. Just because you copied and pasted it from somewhere else on the Internet in no way makes it decent.

Comment: I could have put it in without citing the source seeing as I've often used it. It happens to be the highest up-voted answer, so apparently people don't see principles of decent typesetting as a major issue.

Comment: Thanks. You may be on to something when you remark that many (most?) "people don't see principles of decent typesetting as a major issue. " Deep sigh. I guess Don Knuth, for one, wasn't in that camp when he decided to create TeX... FWIW, I did *not* downvote your posting. I find downvotes rather unhelpful. In fact, I have contributed an upvote just now.